# Spring Data REST - add item to associated collection

Tags: java, spring, http-post, model-associations, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to figure out how to add an item to an associated collection using Spring Data Rest.

According to the [Spring Data REST documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource), POST method is supported for collections, so

```
  curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/uri-list' -d 'http://localhost:8080/artifacts/1' http://localhost:8080/collectors/1/artifacts
```

should add an artifact to the (yet empty) collection. Unfortunately, it does not:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET, DELETE, PATCH, PUT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2015 22:54:59 GMT

{"timestamp":1429311299117,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/collectors/1/artifacts"}
```

My entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Collector {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Artifact> artifacts;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
public class Artifact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "collector_id")
    private Collector owner;
}
```

The complete code is on [Github](https://github.com/endrec/associated-collection-test).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Seems like you are posting to wrong endpoint. Ensure that the mappings Spring data generates when launching your app match the pattern and method.

Comment: The endpoint is fine, I can get a list of Artifacts from the same endpoint. I just can't add a new one to the list.

Comment: First of all you should never serialize entity objects. Use domain objects. Then make sure you have proper constructors available.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, @Vaelyr. Lombok takes care of my constructors (most of the time). Entity objects has to be serializable by nature.

Comment: API should have no clue about entity objects. For good practice you should map them into separate DTO objects which talk to your API, services return entity objects which are mapped into DTO-s. If you ever plan to do any kind of validation using annotations, you will drown into them. Anyway, I can't see what are you posting through curl? `-d 'http://localhost:8080/artifacts/1'` seems wrong? You should be passing in json: `-d '{  "name" : "John",  "artifacts" : [{ "articaftName" : "test" }] }'`

Comment: Entity and domain object separation might be good, but if you have a lok at the spring example projects, you wont see such thing. I am posting a reference in text-uri-list format, as documented on the Spring Data Rest website. I really appreciate your help @Vaelyr, but please, read the whole question first, and try to answer it, and do not solve other problems.

Comment: Spring examples are misleading and made for simplicity. Try to post and pass in `{ "artifact" : "http://localhost:8080/artifacts/1" }` for json type or try just the resource link with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using Spring boot 1.2.4 version which comes with Spring Data Rest 2.2.2. And Spring Data Rest 2.2.2 does not have the feature you needed.

What you needed is Spring Data Rest 2.3.1 which [supports the functionality](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java#L295) you need.